# Illegal group.format parameter in Solr 7.2.1

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I am working with Solr 7.2.1. I have a solr query that results 2 or more groups of resulting document. Now i want all group's result to return as a flat list. For that i am using group.format=simple but solr server is throwing exception. 
Below is the error solr is showing:

"error":{
  "metadata": [
    "error-class",
    "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
    "root-error-class",
    "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
  ],
  "msg": "Illegal group.format parameter",
  "code": 400
}
Please help.

I tried grouping.format=simple but parameter has no impact on resulting document groups

Comment: What does your complete request string (that's giving the error) look like?

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select? group.limit=30 & group.query=(value1:"a b c") & group.query=((value1:a AND value1:b AND value1:c)-(value1:"a b c")) & group.query=((value1:a OR value1:b OR value1:c)-(value1:"a b c") -(value1:a AND value1:b AND value1:c)) & group.sort = option desc &debugQuery=on&group.format=simple &group=true &q=((value1:"a b c")^10 OR(value1:a AND value1:b AND value1:c)^9 ) OR value1:a OR value1:b OR value1:c&rows=15&wt=json

Comment: If you have spaces after each entry (before `&`), then that space is sent as part of the argument. What Solr sees is that you're trying to set the parameter to `simple<space>`, not just `simple`

Comment: Thanks.But I tried that query without spaces too and used group.format=simple but still I am getting result in multiple groups. group.format doesn't seem to work. Can you help on this?

Comment: That's a separate question, so ask it with all the proper details, your example documents, what you're getting and what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

From your example given in the comments above:

```
localhost:8983/solr/core/select? group.limit=30 & group.query=(value1:"a b c") & group.query=((value1:a AND value1:b AND value1:c)-(value1:"a b c")) & group.query=((value1:a OR value1:b OR value1:c)-(value1:"a b c") -(value1:a AND value1:b AND value1:c)) & group.sort = option desc &debugQuery=on&group.format=simple &group=true &q=((value1:"a b c")^10 OR(value1:a AND value1:b AND value1:c)^9 ) OR value1:a OR value1:b OR value1:c&rows=15&wt=json
```

If you have spaces after each entry (before &), then that space is sent as part of the argument. What Solr sees is that you're trying to set the parameter to `simple<space>`, not just `simple`. Simple with a space and the end isn't a valid value for `group.format`.